# A custom datetime struct

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am trying to develop a clock application with images for each digits from 0-9. Wrote a struct that gives me each digits every now and then. Following is the struct.

```
public struct TimeStruct
{
    public DateTime dt
    {
        get
        {
            return DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
    public int s
    {
        get
        {
            return dt.Second;
        }
    }
    public int s2
    {
        get
        {
            return s % 10;
        }

    }
    public int s1
    {
        get
        {
            return s / 10;
        }
    }
    public int m
    {
        get
        {
            return dt.Minute;
        }
    }
    public int m2
    {
        get
        {
            return m % 10;
        }
    }
    public int m1
    {
        get
        {
            return m / 10;
        }
    }
    public int h
    {
        get
        {
            return dt.Hour;
        }
    }
    public int h2
    {
        get
        {
            return h % 10;
        }
    }
    public int h1
    {
        get
        {
            return h / 10;
        }
    }
    public int d
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)dt.DayOfWeek;
        }
    }

}
```

Please guide me to modify this struct so that the prop s2 should be set only when s1 becomes 0. And the same with minutes.
Technology Used : Silverlight
Platform : Windows Phone 7

Was that a bad idea to use struct?

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by "prop s2 should be set only when s1 becomes 0" - what do you want it to do when s1 *isn't* 0? Are you perhaps looking for nullable value types, where s1 would return the null value in some cases?

I have to say, I think this is a pretty confusing type. It has no real state - it's effectively just a bunch of static properties. Any reason for not implementing it as a bunch of static properties, e.g. in a `CurrentDateTime` class? Or just use `DateTime.Now`? Note that if you ask your struct for a bunch of values, one at a time, it may very well give you inconsistent results as time will pass. For example, suppose the time is 1:59:59 and you call `s`, then `m`, then `h` - you may end up getting 59, 59, 2 as the current time rolls over from 1:59:59 to 2:00:00 between the last two calls. If you take the value of `DateTime.Now` just *once* and ask it for all its properties, you'll get a consistent view.

Answer (score 1):

**Why re-invent the wheel ?** Use `DateTime` and `TimeSpan`.